# Dragging multiple layers in JavaScript with KineticJS

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, kineticjs

I'm trying to synchronize dragging of multiple layers. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/e8Z3a/

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: document.getElementById('canvas'),
  width: 600,
  height: 600
});

var imageLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(imageLayer);

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = 'http://laughingsquid.com/wp-content/uploads/Tard2.jpg';

imageObj.onload = function () {
  var image = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj
  });

  imageLayer.add(image);
  imageLayer.setWidth(imageObj.naturalWidth);
  imageLayer.setHeight(imageObj.naturalHeight);

  imageLayer.draw();
};


var drawingLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(drawingLayer);

var mustache = new Kinetic.Polygon({
  points: [
    380, 380,
    410, 350,
    380, 390,
    210, 390,
    180, 350,
    210, 380
  ],
  fill: 'black'
});

drawingLayer.add(mustache);
drawingLayer.draw();

var posX, posY;
imageLayer.on('dragstart', function(event) {
  posX = event.clientX;
  posY = event.clientY;
});

imageLayer.on('dragmove dragend', function(event) {
  drawingLayer.move(event.clientX - posX, event.clientY - posY);
  drawingLayer.draw();

  posX = event.clientX;
  posY = event.clientY;
});

imageLayer.setDraggable(true);
```

The problem is the sync is missing some events. After doing a series of short drags, the mustache layer stays behind, as if it was missing some events on the way.

My observation leads to a guess, that fast dragging works. I mean if you grab the image without moving the mouse, move quickly in random directions, stop the mouse and then let go, layers stay in sync. The problem is with grabbing and letting go while the mouse moves.

Can you teach me how to debug this kind of problems? Is there a TDD-like approach for events related stuff? Any way to maybe record a series of events and than replay it, while adding some debug code? Classic step-by-step debugging is quite useless here...

Comment: The problem you are facing can be solved, but the event causing the problem is pretty much wired into the browser. What would simplify your code creating a group, it works like a container and a node at the same time. So you could add your image and all other drawn items to the group and their positions would be relative to the group, and so all dragging of the group would drag everything relatively. Is there a particular reason you are creating one layer for just a picture and another for drawn items?

Comment: Also, you should try assigning an x,y position to your 'mustache' and move the mustache with setPosition(). Also instead of event.clientX/Y you could use stage.getUserPosition(), gets both the x and y values.

Comment: I'm trying to create interface for marking some features on the picture, with possibility of zooming in and out for high precision. But when zooming in I don't want the markers to get bigger - just the underlying images. Something similar to placemarks on Google Maps.

Comment: About the mustache position - if you mean refactoring, of course I agree. This is just test snippet.
Can you explain what's the difference between event.clientX/Y and stage.getUserPosition()?

Comment: I don't know the exact difference, but getUserPosition is the built in function for KineticJS and is utilized for both mouse and touch events. Basically, getUserPosition will get both the x and y in one go and return an object. ClientX/Y both return integers. Also, its more 'elegant' to use functions... not that that really matters in a small snippet of code.

Comment: Also, if you are experiencing trouble with some function, like the synchronizing of layers, maybe it's better to refactor the code and come up with a simpler solution than to try to synchronize layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go simple,

```
imageLayer.on('dragmove', function() {
    drawingLayer.setAttrs({x:this.getX(), y:this.getY()});
    drawingLayer.draw();
});
```

My example, 
http://jsfiddle.net/QTu8K/38 (updated)

Comment: Is that fiddle working for you guys? I'm on firefox, and it doesn't show anything

Comment: I created a functioning Fiddle with this approach, updated for Kinetic 5: http://jsfiddle.net/QTu8K/38/